# Ellipsoid representation by PSD matrix and by linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Consider the following two representations of ellipsoid:

$$E_1 = \{x \mid x^TSx\leq 1, \, S \succ 0\}$$ 
and $$E_2 = \{y \mid y = Ax, \, \|x\|\leq 1, \,  \det(A) \neq 0\}$$

If I want $E_1=E_2$, I can do

$$x^TSx = x^TS^{1/2}S^{1/2}x = \|S^{1/2}x\|^2_2 \leq 1$$ 
and $$y=Ax \longrightarrow A^{-1}y = x \longrightarrow \|A^{-1}y\| = \|x\| \le1  \longrightarrow \|A^{-1}y\|^2_2\leq 1$$

So comparing both equations,

> $$A^{-1} = S^{1/2}$$

In this case, $A$ has to be symmetric.

However, if I do the following

$$\|A^{-1}y\|^2_2\leq 1 \longrightarrow y^T(AA^T)^{-1}y \leq 1$$

and let $(AA^T)^{-1}=S$ with $S = Q\Lambda Q^T$, $A$ can be chosen as

> $$A = Q\Lambda^{-1/2}$$

In this case, $A$ does not have to be symmetric.

What's wrong with the first approach? Or are both correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S$ does not have to be symmetric, and neither does $A$.

Consider for instance:
$$x^2+2y^2+2xy=
\begin{pmatrix}x&y\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}x&y\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}
$$
It's just that we usually *choose* $S$ to be symmetric, since then we can do a useful eigenvalue decomposition.

Comment: That said, only the symmetric part of $S$ actually contributes to the quadratic form, which is why one usually assumes that it’s symmetric, anyway.

Comment: @amd Exactly, because $x^{\mathsf{T}} A x = x^{\mathsf{T}} \left( \frac{1}{2} A + \frac{1}{2} A^{\mathsf{T}}\right) x$.