# Uniqueness of the ellipsoid representation

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, symmetric-matrices, ellipsoids

I'm studying convex optimization (Boyd's course).

Apprently, an ellipsoid can be described using the set ([see page 22 here)](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxslides.pdf):
$$\mathcal{E}_1 = \{x: (x-c)^T P^{-1} (x-c)\le 1\}$$
where $P$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix.

Another representation is:
$$\mathcal{E}_2 = \{c + A u : ||u|| \le 1\}$$

However, it seems that $\mathcal{E}_1$ is unique but not $\mathcal{E}_2$. I fail to see why! 
Boyd, says though that $\mathcal{E}_2$ can be made unique if $A$ was symmetric positive definite, but I have no clue to as why is that true. Any help is appreciated.

---

## Edit: Trying to find the relationship between $\mathcal{E}_1$ and $\mathcal{E}_2$

For simplicity, assume $c=0$. If $\mathcal{E}_1 = \mathcal{E}_2$, then $x = A u, ||u|| \le 1$ verifies:
$$u^T A^T P^{-1} A u \le 1 \Longleftrightarrow u^T A^T P^{-1/2}P^{-1/2} A u \le 1 \Longleftrightarrow ||P^{-1/2} A u||^2 \le 1.$$

However, for this latter inequality to be verified, we need $Q = P^{-1/2} A$ to be orthogonal (to preserve lengths) because we also have $||u||\le 1$.

We conclude that
$$A = P^{1/2}Q.$$

Because $P$ is symmetric positive definite, we know $P^{1/2}$ is unique. Hence, $A$ is not unique (some would say $A$ is unique up to an orthogonal matrix!).

Now, assuming $Q = H^{1/2}$, where $H$ is symmetric,  we have $A = P^{1/2}H^{1/2}$ and is then unique because $H^{1/2}$ is also unique. In particular, we can choose $H = I$, which gives $A = P^{1/2}$.

Comment: Are you familiar with matrix square roots? $A$ will be $P^{1/2}$ but the matrix square root is not unique (up to an orthogonal matrix). In the simplest case a line segment of length 2 is a 1D ellipsoid. Clearly $\left\{c+u:||u||\le 1\right\}$ and $\left\{c-u:||u||\le 1\right\}$ represent the same "ellipsoid" so $A$ is not unique

Comment: @Casey, thanks. I undertand actually why $A$ is not unique but not why the representation becomes unique if $A$ is symmeteic positive definite.

Comment: @Casey Or why does this symmetric matrix uniquely define the set, is it not anymore known only up to an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: @Casey, I think I got more confused after re-reading your comment. Why's $A= P^{1/2}$?

Comment: "[a positive-semidefinite matrix has precisely one positive-semidefinite square root, which can be called its principal square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix)". Re $A=P^{1/2}$, this is just the parametric form of an ellipse. Take the unit circle, stretch it horizontally by $a$ and vertically by $b$, then rotate it by some angle $\alpha$
$$y = c + U_\alpha\cdot \mathbf{diag}(a,b)\cdot [\cos\theta; \sin\theta]$$
Separately the quadratic form for this ellipse is $U_\alpha\mathbf{diag}(1/a^2,1/b^2)U_\alpha^T$. Hopefully the matrix square root connection is clear

Comment: @Casey, This $A = P^{1/2}$ bugged me quite a bit. I've added and edit where I tried to explain this. Can you please check if what I've put is correct.

Comment: Looks more or less right. I'll put mine here in case you want it 
$$\left\{x:(x-c)^TP^{-1}(x-c) \le 1\right\}$$
$$\left\{x:y^TP^{-T/2}P^{-1/2}y \le 1,\, y = x-c\right\}$$
$$\left\{x:||u||^2\le 1,\, u=P^{-1/2}y,\, y = x-c\right\}$$
$$\left\{x:||u||^2\le 1,\, P^{1/2}u=x-c\right\}$$
$$\left\{x: x = c + P^{1/2}u,\, ||u||^2\le 1 \right\}$$

Comment: @Casey, okay, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ellipsoid representation by PSD matrix and by linear mapping](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019404/ellipsoid-representation-by-psd-matrix-and-by-linear-mapping)